# DataGridViewCellEventArgs behavior?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

When reading C# documentation from Microsoft

[DataGridView.CellValueChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged(v=vs.110).aspx)

[DataGridViewCellEventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcelleventargs(v=vs.110).aspx)

I can't figure out case when the Properties RowIndex is supposed to return -1.

I got this case when bound to the DataGridView.CellValueChanged Event  and updating the  DataGridViewTextBoxColumn ( <=> updating one Column Header ).

Somehow it makes sense but is there somewhere some stronger documentation or specification about this behavior ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataGridViewCellEventArgs gets RowIndex from DataGridViewCell.

documentation for [DataGridViewCell.RowIndex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.rowindex(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1) says:

> The index of the row that contains the cell; -1 if there is no owning row.
>
> When the RowIndex property returns -1, the cell is either a column header, or the cell's row is shared.

a similar case is with [DataGridViewCell.ColumnIndex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.columnindex(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The index of the column that contains the cell; -1 if the cell is not contained within a column.
>
> The column index for the row that contains the row headers has a value of -1.